# How to extract azureocr from multiple images which was stored in azure blob storage

Tags: python, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, ocr, azure-cognitive-services

I am sending multiple images to azureblobstorage using python code now I need to perform azure ocr on those multiple images and save the results and confidence level in Excel sheet

I don't know what is next step I mean how to extract ocr from multiple images I searched many documentation which was provided by Microsoft but still I didn't find the answer

I am trying to import BlobServiceClient but I am getting import error like BlobServiceClient cannot be imported from azure.blob.storage

Comment: there are [SDK/REST Api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/concept-ocr) which uses url of the image which you can use . Now the url of your image would be some thing like this   `Enpoint/containerName/BlobName` now fileName would also have to be included if it exits , then it will be added between blobname and container name. So, using blob storage sdk you can list blobs in the azure blob storage , then you can iterate through that list to call the REST Api/SDK client.

Comment: @MohitGanorkar I have uploaded multiple images in blob storage
For example in blob_urls=[url1,url2,url3] was there now how to iterate through Restapi/sdk to receive ocr extration

Comment: well I you use this [SDK](https://pypi.org/project/azure-storage-blob/) then you can call `.list `method on the container client which will return a list of blob and you can iterate through that refer this [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blobs-list-python#use-a-flat-listing) for it . Also refer this [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-python?tabs=managed-identity,roles-azure-portal,sign-in-azure-cli) to create the container client

Comment: I am unable to import BlobService Client I am getting import error

Comment: Can you please add this error details in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Here I installed the following packaged

  1. azure-storage-blob
  2. azure-cognitiveservices-vision-computervisio

using `pip install <Package Name>`

- Now you can use the following code which is printing the line extracted and the confidence for each line of the image.

```
// Get the following values from portal : 

blob_storage_Connection_String = ""
Cognitive_Service_key = ""
Cognitive_Service_endpoint = ""
container_name = "testcontainer"
storage_account_name = ""

blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(blob_storage_Connection_String)

computervision_client = ComputerVisionClient(Cognitive_Service_endpoint, CognitiveServicesCredentials(Cognitive_Service_key))

container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)

// List of Blobs
blob_list = container_client.list_blobs()

for blob  in  blob_list:
    blob_url = "https://"+storage_account_name+".blob.core.windows.net/"+container_name+"/"+blob.name
    read_response = computervision_client.read(blob_url, raw=True)
    read_operation_location = read_response.headers["Operation-Location"]
    operation_id = read_operation_location.split("/")[-1]
    while  True:
        read_result = computervision_client.get_read_result(operation_id)
        if  read_result.status not  in ['notStarted', 'running']:
            break
        time.sleep(1)
    for  textresult  in  read_result.analyze_result.read_results:
        for  line  in  textresult.lines:
            print("Text: ",line.text)
            print("Confidence: ", line.appearance.style.confidence)
```

- Here I have 2 images in the azure storage container thus there are two sets of results

Output :

[image]

- Further you can add the `line.text` and `line.appearance.style.confidence` in excel sheet by using `xlwt` module. Refer this [Article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/writing-excel-sheet-using-python/) by `aishwarya.27`  on adding data to excel.